# Trying to move my image across the screen using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make the img move across the screen. Using ASDZ I would like the img to react to the jquery input. However, my code is not functioning properly. Can anyone help me with this? The image is not moving when I press ASDW.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Plane Dodge</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='planegame.css'/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="planegame.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="airplane.png">
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
img {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

body{
    background-image: url("skygrad.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).keydown(function (key) {
        switch (parseInt(key.which, 10)) {
        case 65: //a
            $('img').animate({
                left: "-=10px"
            }, 'fast');
            break;
        case 83: //s
            $('img').animate({
                top: "+=10px"
            }, 'fast');
            break;
        case 87: //w
            $('img').animate({
                top: "-=10px"
            }, 'fast');
            break;
        case 68: //d
            $('img').animate({
                left: "+=10px"
            }, 'fast');
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: First question just to be sure...The shown css and jquery are actually in the head style sheet and script correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "my code is not functioning properly"? What exactly is not working? The code works pretty well.

Comment: Did you mean "ASDZ"? Right now the code is setup to react to "ASDW"

Comment: I edited the code. Maybe the html is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Works OK for me. I changed the animation to CSS animation to make it a little more smooth.

http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/CLpCj/

```
transition:all .2s ease-out;
```